# Cannot start Outlook web add-in

Tags: outlook, office365-apps

I have an issue trying to load and debug any kind of Outlook web add-in.  I can reproduce with my own add-in (which is deployed to the Office store and used to work in debug mode perfectly!) as well as with the default add-in template in Visual Studio 2017.  I create a default "OutlookWebAddin1" project, change nothing, hit F5 to deploy and run/debug, enter my credentials, and load the add-in in the Outlook client or browser (Chrome, IE and Edge) - all exhibit the error:

```
"Add-in Error: Something went wrong and we couldn't start this add-in.  
Please try again later or contact your system administrator."
```

The F12 console in Chrome (to pick one of the three browsers I tested with), shows these errors:

```
GET https://localhost:44398/MessageRead.html?et=&_host_Info=
Outlook|Web|16.01|en-CA|11aa92ad-a510-ddb9-c441-529b1b374f16| 
net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
GET https://localhost:44398/Images/icon64.png net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
Executing action: GetTaskStatusAction
GET https://outlook.office365.com/ows/outlookusersettings/api/v1/frepanel
/frepaneltaskstatus 401 (Unauthorized)
```

Here's a prettier look at the error:

https://www.screencast.com/t/elcbcUkdlkO

Comment: Did you try to run in VS 2015? I have issues with vs 2017 . And, did you try to add the localhost address to trusted sites? https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/BLOivjDTTW0

Comment: Same problem with VS2015! http://localhost was already in trusted sites

Comment: On a hunch I tried incognito mode and a different Office 365 tenant and mailbox - same problem. I use multiple accounts frequently, and that used to be an issue back in the Agave days.

Comment: Sounds wired . When it's start to show you this error message ? you do something before it's start to show the message ? because I guess that it's work for you sometime...?
Try to ask also in the MDN forum : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/home?forum=appsforoffice

Comment: It shows this error message as soon as the add-in loads (by clicking on the add-in command button to open the task pane). It shows this error every time. I tried on another PC with VS 2015 with a brand new project and the error STILL occurs! There are indeed related threads in MSDN about https issues and perhaps a bad VS update but I can't find any solutions: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9ec1fbc0-b604-4e8e-961f-b96c46e9a6a6/office-365-outlook-addin-difficulty-executing?forum=outlookdev

Comment: Another thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8905a2e6-d5e3-4d8b-9243-d5c4e63e1c0c/after-upgrade-to-visual-studio-update-3-cant-debug-office-addins-online-since-ssl-no-longer-works?forum=appsforoffice

Answer (score 1):

The cause is apparently a problem with the localhost certificate.  The fix is to use the Certificates Snap-In in MS Management Console and copy the localhost certificate from "Personal-> Certificates" to "Trusted Root Certification Authorities -> Certificates".  How this problem occurred on two very different PCs with different versions of Visual Studio is a mystery, but this does work.